# Downside/Performace Impact in using reactive spring data (mongdb) with blocking methods

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I am very new to reactive programming, and currently working on microservice where in spring mvc is used and Spring Data MongoDb for database connectivity.

As I am going through spring data mongo db docs, there is support for reactive repositories, reative template api etc.

So Is there going to be any downside if I choose to use reactive templates and repository with blocking nature ?

```
Ex.    
reactiveMongoTemplate.add(entity).block()
reactiveMongoTemplate.update(id, entity).block()
```

Also is there any significant difference with using calls like above than using blocking repository and template api itself ?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on which stack you use: Spring WebFlux or Spring Web MVC.

In case of **Spring WebFlux** the choice is obvious: you have to **use ReactiveMongoTemplate** and **never call** `block` on it, instead return Mono/Flux as you get it from the template.

In case of **Spring Web MVC** you are free to use both the regular blocking MongoTemplate and ReactiveMongoTemplate with `block`. Although, in most cases you should **go with the good old MongoTemplate** for sake of simplicity and performance. ReactiveMongoTemplate has some overhead compared to the blocking MongoTemplate because the reactive types Mono/Flux put some additional pressure on memory.

I can imagine one use case where ReactiveMongoTemplate can provide some advantage even in Spring MVC: when during one HTTP request you have to execute multiple Mono operations concurrently. If you used blocking MongoTemplate then you would need to set up a thread pool and delegate the query execution there. However, with ReactiveMongoTemplate you could use the many operators of Mono and Flux to accomplish this task without worrying about threads, thread pools and scaling issues.

Answer (score 1):

In the traditional programming you usually own the thread that you're running on, in the reactive programming its not the case. This "underlying unit of execution" (cpu resources consumer if you wish) is not yours, but rather a "global" thing that currently happens to execute your task, but can switch to do other things really soon.

So when you block, you say to this "global unit of execution" like "hey, stop doing anything else, wait for me". In the traditional approach, its kind of ok, because you have a thread associated with the current request, other requests (or flows if your system is not web based) are supposed to be executed with other threads taken from a fairly large thread pool. In the reactive system however, its not the case since you're trying to utilize a small amount of these "global units of execution".

Ok, so if you block, the events all over the place will stop emitting and will get start to buffer. And this may lead to the whole system becoming unusable.